# drawing on the iPhone in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing on the iPhone in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397567/drawing-on-the-iphone-in-objective-c)

I have written this...

In the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DrawView : UIView {
    CGPoint gestureStartPoint,currentPosition;
    CGContextRef c;
    UIBezierPath *currentPath;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)UIBezierPath *currentPath;

@end
```

And in the .m file:

```
#import "DrawView.h"

@implementation DrawView

@synthesize currentPath;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [self drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        currentPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
        currentPath.lineWidth=3;
    }
    return self;
}




- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    [currentPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self]; 
    [currentPath addLineToPoint:(currentPosition)];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    [currentPath moveToPoint:(gestureStartPoint)];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

I want to let the user draw an image on the iPhone screen and then use that image for the game... but this doesn't draw anything...

Comment: So... this is the 3rd time you're asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your currentPath is not allocated.
If you instantiate the view in the resource [UIView initWithFrame:] will never be called. 
Implement [UIView initWithCoder:] and allocate it there.

```
- (void)commonInit
{
    currentPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    currentPath.lineWidth=3;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Alternatively you can make the path in the touchesBegan if it is nil.

```
- (UIBezierPath*)currentPath
{
    if (currentPath = nil)
    {
        currentPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
        currentPath.lineWidth=3;
    }
    return currentPath;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    [[self currentPath] moveToPoint:(gestureStartPoint)];
}
```

However, there are some problems in the code.

1. You call [self drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] before self = [super initWithFrame:frame]. You must not call any method there. You can write your code only inside

   if (self ! =nil)
   {
       // your code
   }
2. currentPath leaks. Release it in dealloc.
3. Never call drawRect directly. Call [UIView setNeedsDisplay] instead.

Comment: could you please give me some code? i kind of understand but code would help...

Comment: By the way, never call drawRect directly. You need to call [UIView setNeedsDisplay].

Comment: wait.....why is it always the same guy closing me?